# I hope that you relieved

Tags: direct-objects

*I promise you that I will not make any attempt to contact you. **I hope that you relieved**.*

This is supposed to be the reply to the addresse from whom I wanted some help but he did not bother to answer. I would like to ask if the second sentence is OK. I want to express in an ironical way that was a load off his mind. Not sure whether the verb "relieve" takes the object.

Comment: The past participle here acts as an adjectival, and needs a copula: "I hope that you **are** relieved."

Comment: Please do not take Sina's advice. There is no word "releave" and if Sina means "relieve", then "I hope it helps you relieve" is meaningless.

Comment: @Colin Fine you're right. It is wrong. I didn't notice at first. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say

> I hope that you relieved

you will leave the reader hanging: "relieved *what*"? which wouldn't make sense in the context of this passage.

You probably want the person to feel "relief" that they will not be contacted and so

> I hope you *are* relieved *(that I will not be contacting you)*

is more appropriate.

@StoneyB gives the technical reason for the construction.